# Storyboard or xib for PSCollectionView

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uicollectionview

In my app I will use the PSCollectionView I found on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13684158/how-to-implement-pscollectionview-in-iphone-app) how to work with PSCollectionView, but it doesn't explain if it's necessary to create a storyboard or a xib file. If I've to create a storyboard or xib which controller I should implement?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The readme says : `It's the equivalent of UITableViewCell` and you also have a delegate method

```
- (UIView *)collectionView:(PSCollectionView *)collectionView cellForRowAtIndex:(NSInteger)index
```

So as for a normal table view, this method will be called to fill the table. But as you can see, this method has to return a UIView. This view can be programmatically coded, or you can designed one in a .xib file an load it like this :

```
NSArray *nibContent = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"myCustomView" owner:self options:nil];
UIView *myView = (UIView*)[nibContent objectAtIndex:0];
```